# Javascript code not running in browser

Tags: javascript, html, web

I have following javascript code and I am trying to run it on Google Chrome and Internet Explorer but in both I get a blank page. I can't understand what is the error in the script?
Please tell me what is wrong with it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         <title>Changing Background Color</title>


    </head>

    <body>
        <script type= "text/javascript">
            document.write( "test run");
            var colors={"red","orange","green","blue","brown","purple","gray","white"}
            var index=0;
            function changecolor()
            {
                 for(index=0;colorindex<colors.length;index++)
                 {
                     document.bgcolor=colors[index];
                 }
            }
            function startchange()
            {
                setinterval("changecolor()",3000);
            }
            window.onload=startchange();
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  The browser has debugging tools, take a look at those.

Comment: The object literal in this code looks like it'll produce a syntax error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` are you sure you didn't mean to write an array literal instead?

Comment: Also, there is no `;` after the colors object

Comment: @Marc-AndréTrahan that isn't actually a big deal here, however it is best practice to include them.

Comment: This question should not be posted here.  Elemental debugging by looking in the browser error console would show errors.  Please immediately learn how to do that so you can see why your own scripts are not running and where the errors are.  Then, you can post here only when you have the list of errors and can't figure out how to correct one.

Answer (score 1):

A small typo, instead of `bgcolor` it should be `bgColor`

Hope it helps .. :)

Comment: I am just a beginner. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A few typos and a syntax error where you used the wrong type of brackets for an *Array*,

```
var colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "brown", "purple", "gray", "white"], // array literal
    index = 0;
function changecolor() {
     for (index = 0; index < colors.length; ++index) { // fix typo
         document.bgColor = colors[index]; // typo
     }
     // are you sure you wanted this loop and not to do something like
     // document.bgColor = colors[++index % colors.length];
     // ?
}
function startchange() {
    setInterval(changecolor, 3000); // typo, pass function in directly
}
window.onload = startchange; // set function, not invoke function
```

Also, your `for` loop will apply the changes faster than a human would see them, are you sure you wanted this behaviour? See my comments above for what you may have intended

Comment: Thank you Sir. I am a beginner in javascript. and after fixing mentioned typos I got it running. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.write()
```

overwrites the current document, so all your JavaScript is lost. Remove it, or use alert() instead.

Comment: `document.write` won't call `document.open` if the document is already open - i.e. page hasn't been fully interpreted yet - but yes, it's not a good function to use. Neither is `alert`, use `console.log`

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax issues with your code.

First, you need to remove the quotes (`"`) and `()`s from `setInterval` and capitalize the `I`.

```
setInterval(changecolor, 3000);
```

The `setInterval` function takes in two arguments: a callback function (which can be a local variable such as your `changecolor` function) and a number (the number of milliseconds for the interval).

You also need to declare your array properly with `[` and `]` instead of `{` and `}`. Also (although not necessary) include a `;` at the end of the statement.

```
var colors = ["red", "orange", "green", "blue", "brown", "purple", "gray", "white"];
```

As [Tarun Gaba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1521172/tarun-gaba) pointed out, you should use `bgColor` instead of `bgcolor`.

Comment: Please include **why** the `setInterval` needs to be changed. Also, the semicolon is not needed - [see this](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).